# Argument of type CustomError is not assignable to Error in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Why is my typescript reference my custom error giving me the error `Argument of type CustomError is not assignable to parameter of type Error in Typescript`

My Errors class

```
module Errors {

    export declare class Error  {
            public name: string;
            public message: string;
            public stack: string;
            constructor(message?: string);
    }

    export class CustomError extends Error {
        constructor(message: string) {
            super(message);
            this.name = 'invalid parameters error';
            this.message = message || 'the parameters for the request or call are incorrect.';
            this.stack = (<any>new Error()).stack;
        }
    }
}
```

and in code returning a bluebird promise from Sequelize.

```
    var Promise = require('bluebird');
    var import Errors = require('./errors')

    //using fs here for an example, it can be any bluebird promise

    fs.readFileAsync("file.json").catch(Errors.InvalidParameterError, e => { //this is typescript compiler error
                return reply(Boom.badRequest())
            })
```

Comment: The code posted doesn't give enough information to diagnose the problem. Which line of code actually has the error? It's not clear where you're consuming `CustomError` from. What are the types of `reply`, `getFromDbPromise`, and `Errors.InvalidParameterError` ?

Comment: the error comes from the catch function - I'll simplify the example.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that `lib.d.ts` declares `Error` as interface and variable, but not a class.

**Option 1.** Implement `Error` interface and inherit via `util.inherits`

```
import util = require('util');

module Errors {
    export class CustomError implements Error {
        name: string;
        message: string;

        constructor(message: string) {
            Error.call(this);
            Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
            this.name = 'invalid parameters error';
            this.message = message || 'the parameters for the request or call are incorrect.';
        }
    }

    util.inherits(CustomError, Error);
}

export = Errors;
```

Note, `captureStackTrace` is not declared in default declaration, so you should declare it in onw `.d.ts` file:

```
interface ErrorConstructor {
    captureStackTrace(error: Error, errorConstructor: Function);
}
```

**Option 2.** Without class sugar

```
module Errors {
    export var CustomError = <ErrorConstructor>function (message: string) {
        Error.call(this);
        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
        this.name = 'invalid parameters error';
        this.message = message || 'the parameters for the request or call are incorrect.';
    }

    util.inherits(CustomError, Error);
}
```

**Option 3.** Pure TypeScript way

Declaration file (not necessary because of duck typing):

```
declare type ErrorInterface = Error;
```

Errors module:

```
module Errors {
    declare class Error implements ErrorInterface {
        name: string;
        message: string;
        static captureStackTrace(object, objectConstructor?);
    }

    export class CustomError extends Error {
        constructor(message: string) {
            super();
            Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
            this.name = 'invalid parameters error';
            this.message = message || 'the parameters for the request or call are incorrect.';
        }
    }
}

export = Errors;
```

**Also check if you have right catch declaration:**

```
catch(e: Error) // wrong
catch(e: { new (message?: string): Error }) // right
```

Comment: your answer is great!